# Why does this ruby mechanize code throw undefined method?

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

I'm picking up ruby mechanize & getting tripped up from the start...

Why does this code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby env
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'mechanize'

    agent = Mechanize.new
    page = agent.get('http://linkedin.com/')

    #pp page

    form = page.form.first
    #form.fields.each { |f| puts f.name }
    #pp page
```

spit out...

```
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.4/lib/mechanize/form.rb:217:in `method_missing': undefined method `first' for #<Mechanize::Form:0x007f9f2cf1ced0> (NoMethodError)
from 1-li.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `forms` method instead of the `form` method.

Per the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize/Page#forms-instance_method), the `forms` method returns "a list of all form tags", and you can then method-chain a `first` method.  For example:

```
require 'mechanize'
mechanize = Mechanize.new
page = mechanize.get('http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp')
forms = page.forms
forms.class              #=> Array
form = forms.first
form.class               #=> Mechanize::Form
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first form on the page, use use `page.form` or `page.forms.first`